# Basic Authentication of spring with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, spring, restangular

I am using Restangular with Spring's oauth security and in the client side i am using Restangular for login request.

Code in OAuth2ServerConfiguration:

```
   @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()

                .withClient("clientapp")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .secret("abc");
        }
```

Login with postman needs these configurations:

```
1-Set Authorization as "Basic Auth".
2-Set username,password as {"username":"clientapp","password":"abc"}//credentials to access server side
3-In request body through "x-www-form-urlencoded" three parameters are sent.
  {"username":"abc@gmail.com","password":"abc123","grant_type":"password"}//credentials to login which are checked from database.
```

This will do a successful login.but i cannot understand how to use these configurations in Angular JS Restangular call.

currently m trying with this.

In Config:

```
    RestangularProvider.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
   return RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({ "Authorization": "Basic Y2xpZW50YXBwOkxNUw==",
        "username":"clientapp",
        "password":"abc",
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
            });
```

In Controller:

```
     Restangualar.all("oauth/login").post({username;$scope.user.username,
     password:"$scope.user.password","grant_type":"password"}).then(function(){
 console.log(res);
  });
```

But I am getting this error:

```
  error:"unauthorized",error_description:"Full authentication is required to access this resource"
```

in browser.

Note:This resource is not secured.

Any Solution???

**Update:** I forgot to added a main information that my frontend with angular is running independently on *localhost(through xampp)* while spring login backend is on *localhost:8080*..

Error in network tab:

[image]

2-

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            //.antMatchers("/users").permitAll()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
         .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

3-

```
  endpoints
            .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {

                public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest hsr,         HttpServletResponse rs, Object o,FilterChain chain) throws Exception {
                    rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",  "GET,OPTIONS,POST");
                   // rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "7200");
                    rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-  Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
                    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) hsr;
                    if (httpServletRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
                      chain.doFilter(hsr, rs);
                    } else {
                        // In case of HTTP OPTIONS method, just return the response
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

It seems to be a CORS problem, lots of answers already for it, but in your case using XAMPP you will need to configure your apache server:

https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html.

PREVIOUS ANSWER BEFORE UPDATE:

The advantage of using restangular is the ability to manage resources in a more semantic way and the ability to get nested resources. All these advantages don't really apply for a call just to retrieve a token from an oauth2 provider.

I would recommend to forget about using restangular for this specific call (you still can use it for everything else in your application) and convert this call to a simple $http.post.

```
$http.post('oauth/login', 
           {  username;$scope.user.username,
              password:"$scope.user.password",
              "grant_type":"password"
           }, 
           {
                headers: { "Authorization": "Basic Y2xpZW50YXBwOkxNUw==",
                           "username":"clientapp",
                           "password":"abc",
                           "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
                         }
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({
                     "Authorization": "Bearer " + response.token
                });
            });
```

So, you just use $http.post, and on its response set the default headers in angular to use the retrieved token.

Cheers,

Comment: I have used same configuration in the http and also with restangular in the frontend on the same domain(both on localhost:8080). it worked there but same is not working on separate domain.

Comment: If that is the case it sounds like a CORS issue, have you checked what is the failed response when it fails?

Comment: error:"unauthorized",error_description:"Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Comment: That will be the error you get in your application, but if you look at the networks tab of chrome debugger, you will see your request to get the token and its response, what does it say?

Comment: You need to configure your server to provide with the correct headers to allow CORS. Read about it, the problem is in there, your code probably is correct. https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Restangular custom post. See [documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#custom-methods).

Example:

```
Restangular.service("/oauth/login").one().customPOST(
  {},
  '',
  {
    // Params...
    grant_type: 'password',
    client_id: 'clientapp',
    client_secret: 'abc',
    username: 'abc@gmail.com',
    password: 'abc123',
    scope: 'read, write'
  },
  {
    // headers...
  }).then(
    function (response) {
      // Manage successfull response
    },
    function () {
      // Manage error response
    }
);
```

Hope it helps